# In \task environment, now to turn off enumeration for a single line of text?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, two-column

OP code revised to insert `\task*` to force a line of text flush left within task environment. (h/t @JohnKormylo)

But I need to turn off enumeration for the 2 lines of text below:

[image]

[image]

(Note: This test key has several sections that are **not** sequentially numbered. That's why I didn't create them as formal subheaders. **A mistake?**)

**One other question** regarding line spacing between steps of the solution. Is using `\bigskip` (with the definition `\def\bigskip{\vskip\bigskipamount}` the most efficient way of creating vertical space to enhance readability of the individual solution steps?

Thanks very much for taking time to review/respond to this post.

mwe

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}
\printanswers
% un-comment to print solutions.
\renewcommand{\solutiontitle}{}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=0.5in,include head]{geometry}

\pagestyle{head}
%Note: \& forces & to be literal character
\header{Algebra II: Unit 11 Quiz (Rational Expressions \& Equations)}
       {}
       {Due 04/07/23} 

\newcommand{\pagetop}{%
\noindent 
  
  \bigskip
  \vspace{0.5mm}
}

\settasks{after-item-skip=1em,
          after-skip=2cm,
          label-width=1.5em, %<---------
          item-indent=2em,   %<---------
          label=(\arabic*),
          column-sep=1em     %<----------
          }

\begin{document}
%definition for bigskip = 1 line to replace all \bigskip
\def\bigskip{\vskip\bigskipamount}

\textbf{1-2 Simplify each expression.}
\begin{tasks}
[style=enumerate](2)
% Prob #1
\task $\dfrac{4x+12}{x^2+5x+6}$
\\
\begin{solutionorbox}[3cm]
$\dfrac{4(x+3)}
{(x+3)(x+2)}$
\bigskip
$\dfrac{4\cancel{(x+3)}}{\cancel{(x+3)}(x+2)} = \boldsymbol{\dfrac{4}{x+2}}$
\end{solutionorbox}

\vspace{0.25cm}

% Prob #2
\task $\dfrac{x^2+3x+2}{x^2-4}$
\bigskip
\begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]
$\dfrac{(x+2)(x+1)}{(x+2)(x-2)}$
\bigskip
$\dfrac{\cancel{(x+2)}}{\cancel{x+2}(x-2)} = \boldsymbol{\dfrac{x+1}{x-2}}$
\bigskip
\end{solutionorbox}
\vspace{0.25cm}

\textbf{3-4: Multiply or divide. Simply.}
% Prob #3
\task $\dfrac{p^2-7p+10}{p^2-25}$
\bigskip
\begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]
Factor both numerator and denominator. Notice numerator is a perfect square. 
\bigskip
$\dfrac{(p-5)(p-2)}{(p+5)(p-5)}$
\bigskip
$\dfrac{{\cancel{(p-5)}}(p-2)}{{(p+5)\cancel{(p-5)}}}=\boldsymbol{\dfrac{p-2}{p+5}}$ 
 \end{solutionorbox}
\vspace{0.25cm}
% Prob #4
\task $\dfrac{n^2+6n-7}{n^2+14n+49}$
\bigskip
\begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]
Factor both numerator and denominator.
\bigskip
$\dfrac{(n+7)(n-1)}{(n+7)(n+7)}$
\bigskip
Cancel factors.
\bigskip
$\dfrac{{\cancel{(n+7)}(n-1)}}{\cancel{(n+7)}(n+7)}=\boldsymbol{\dfrac{n-1}{n+7}}$  
\end{solutionorbox}
\vspace{0.25cm}
% Prob #5
\task $\dfrac{7}{k+7}\boldsymbol{\cdot} \dfrac{k^2+9k+18}{k+3}$
\bigskip
\begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]
Factor both numerator and denominator.
\bigskip
$\dfrac{(n+7)(n-1)}{(n+7)(n+7)}$
\bigskip
Cancel factors.
\bigskip
$\dfrac{{\cancel{(n+7)}(n-1)}}{\cancel{(n+7)}(n+7)}=\boldsymbol{\dfrac{n-1}{n+7}}$  
\end{solutionorbox}
\vspace{0.25cm}
\end{tasks}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Use \task* (see page 4, section 3.3).

Comment: @JohnKormylo  ...Thanks very much for your helpful response. One followup question...please...how to I turn off the enumeration for this single line, i.e. ** (5) 5-8: Add / Subtract. If possible, simplify answer. **

Comment: I don't think you can do that with tasks.  I might be able to achieve the desired effect with paracol.

Comment: Appreciate you responding. Can you please suggest the proper \paracol code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `\fullwidth` is about indentation, not columns.  `\globalcounter*` prevents each column from having separate question numbars.  `\switcholumn*` aligns the tops for the next set of columns.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}
\printanswers
% un-comment to print solutions.
\renewcommand{\solutiontitle}{}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{framed}
%\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{paracol}
\globalcounter*
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=0.5in,include head]{geometry}

\pagestyle{head}
%Note: \& forces & to be literal character
\header{Algebra II: Unit 11 Quiz (Rational Expressions \& Equations)}
       {}
       {Due 04/07/23} 

\newcommand{\pagetop}{%
\noindent 
  
  \bigskip
  \vspace{0.5mm}
}

\begin{document}
%definition for bigskip = 1 line to replace all \bigskip
\def\bigskip{\vskip\bigskipamount}

\begin{questions}
\fullwidth{\textbf{1-2 Simplify each expression.}}
\begin{paracol}{2}
% Prob #1
\question $\dfrac{4x+12}{x^2+5x+6}$
\\
\begin{solutionorbox}[3cm]
$\dfrac{4(x+3)}
{(x+3)(x+2)}$
\bigskip
$\dfrac{4\cancel{(x+3)}}{\cancel{(x+3)}(x+2)} = \boldsymbol{\dfrac{4}{x+2}}$
\end{solutionorbox}

\switchcolumn

% Prob #2
\question $\dfrac{x^2+3x+2}{x^2-4}$
\bigskip
\begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]
$\dfrac{(x+2)(x+1)}{(x+2)(x-2)}$
\bigskip
$\dfrac{\cancel{(x+2)}}{\cancel{x+2}(x-2)} = \boldsymbol{\dfrac{x+1}{x-2}}$
\bigskip
\end{solutionorbox}

\switchcolumn*[\fullwidth{\textbf{3-4: Multiply or divide. Simply.}}]
%\end{paracol}% alternate version
%\fullwidth{\textbf{3-4: Multiply or divide. Simply.}}
%\begin{paracol}{2}

% Prob #3
\question $\dfrac{p^2-7p+10}{p^2-25}$
\bigskip
\begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]
Factor both numerator and denominator. Notice numerator is a perfect square. 
\bigskip
$\dfrac{(p-5)(p-2)}{(p+5)(p-5)}$
\bigskip
$\dfrac{{\cancel{(p-5)}}(p-2)}{{(p+5)\cancel{(p-5)}}}=\boldsymbol{\dfrac{p-2}{p+5}}$ 
 \end{solutionorbox}

\switchcolumn

% Prob #4
\question $\dfrac{n^2+6n-7}{n^2+14n+49}$
\bigskip
\begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]
Factor both numerator and denominator.
\bigskip
$\dfrac{(n+7)(n-1)}{(n+7)(n+7)}$
\bigskip
Cancel factors.
\bigskip
$\dfrac{{\cancel{(n+7)}(n-1)}}{\cancel{(n+7)}(n+7)}=\boldsymbol{\dfrac{n-1}{n+7}}$  
\end{solutionorbox}

\switchcolumn*

\question $\dfrac{7}{k+7}\boldsymbol{\cdot} \dfrac{k^2+9k+18}{k+3}$
\bigskip
\begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]
Factor both numerator and denominator.
\bigskip
$\dfrac{(n+7)(n-1)}{(n+7)(n+7)}$
\bigskip
Cancel factors.
\bigskip
$\dfrac{{\cancel{(n+7)}(n-1)}}{\cancel{(n+7)}(n+7)}=\boldsymbol{\dfrac{n-1}{n+7}}$  
\end{solutionorbox}
\vspace{0.25cm}
\end{paracol}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for fixing my code! Since I create many of these 2 column answer keys and test, your code revision is something I will use frequently going forward. Your generous assistance has saved me hours of fruitless toil! Your explanation of ```\fullwidth``` and ```\globalcounter``` is especially helpful because these commands are new to me.

Comment: What package documentation should I read to understand more fully ```fullwidth``` , ```\globalcounter``` and ```\switcholumn``` ?

Comment: `\fullwidth` is from exam class, while `\globalcounter` and `\switchcolumn` are from paracol.  I revised the solution to use the (second) optional argument for `\switchcolumn*`.