# Pgfplots: need to force left two coordinate planes to avoid right hand bleed

Tags: pgfplots, horizontal-alignment

In this worksheet, I elected to increase the size of coordinate plane so students could more easily graph the equations.

`\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.18}`

The result causes the coordinate plane in the right hand column to bleed off the page.

[image]

Besides reducing the `\plotset{width=`, can a line of code force the planes in both the L & R columns to the left to utilize the blank space in the L margin?

Thanks very much for taking the time to assist me!

mwe

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=0.5in,include head]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{systeme}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.18}

\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{enumitem,tasks}
\settasks{
%  after-item-skip=5em,
%  after-skip=2cm,
  label-width=2em,
  item-indent=3em,
  label=(\arabic*),
  column-sep=2em,
 }
 \pagestyle{head}
\header{\textbf{Algebra II: Quadratic Systems}}
{}
{ 04/17/23} 
\begin{document}

\textbf {SET A: Solve each system by graphing.}

\begin{tasks}(2)
%Prob #1
\task* $\syslineskipcoeff{1}\systeme*{y=2(x+4)^2-5, y=-2x-9}$\\
\bigskip
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            axis lines=middle,
            axis line style={-stealth,shorten >=-3mm},
            xlabel=$x$, xlabel style={anchor=south west},
            ylabel=$y$, ylabel style={anchor=south east},
            grid=both,
            grid style={draw=gray!25},
            ticklabel style={font=\scriptsize, text=black!50, inner sep=1pt},
            xmin=-10,   xmax=10,          
            ymin=-10,   ymax=10,
            xtick distance=2,
            ytick distance=2,
            minor tick num=1,
            tick align=outside,
        ]
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
%Prob #2
  \task* $\syslineskipcoeff{1}\systeme*{y=2(x+4)^2-3, y=x+7}$\\
\bigskip
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            axis lines=middle,
            axis line style={-stealth,shorten >=-3mm},
            xlabel=$x$, xlabel style={anchor=south west},
            ylabel=$y$, ylabel style={anchor=south east},
            grid=both,
            grid style={draw=gray!25},
            ticklabel style={font=\scriptsize, text=black!50, inner sep=1pt},
            xmin=-10,   xmax=10,          
            ymin=-10,   ymax=10,
            xtick distance=2,
            ytick distance=2,
            minor tick num=1,
            tick align=outside,
        ]
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
%Prob #3
\task* $\syslineskipcoeff{1}\systeme*
{y=2(x-3)^2+1, 2x+y=11}$\\
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            axis lines=middle,
            axis line style={-stealth,shorten >=-3mm},
            xlabel=$x$, xlabel style={anchor=south west},
            ylabel=$y$, ylabel style={anchor=south east},
            grid=both,
            grid style={draw=gray!25},
            ticklabel style={font=\scriptsize, text=black!50, inner sep=1pt},
            xmin=-10,   xmax=10,          
            ymin=-10,   ymax=10,
            xtick distance=2,
            ytick distance=2,
            minor tick num=1,
            tick align=outside,
        ]
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}        
%Prob #4
\task* $\syslineskipcoeff{1}\systeme*
{y=\frac{1}{2}(x-4)^2-3, y=2x-11}$\\
\bigskip
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            axis lines=middle,
            axis line style={-stealth,shorten >=-3mm},
            xlabel=$x$, xlabel style={anchor=south west},
            ylabel=$y$, ylabel style={anchor=south east},
            grid=both,
            grid style={draw=gray!25},
            ticklabel style={font=\scriptsize, text=black!50, inner sep=1pt},
            xmin=-10,   xmax=10,          
            ymin=-10,   ymax=10,
            xtick distance=2,
            ytick distance=2,
            minor tick num=1,
            tick align=outside,
        ]
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{tasks}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Be warned that exam class is not really compatible with geometry page margins to begin with.  Second, it is easier to overlap margins than change them.  `\hspace*{-1cm}` or so before the tikzpicture would help.  `\makebox[\linewidth]{...}` will center the contents relative to the column (assujing tasks uses columns).

Comment: Good grief, you are still doing all the things I told you not to do in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/682166/in-task-environment-now-to-turn-off-enumeration-for-a-single-line-of-text

Comment: I took a liberty and change question title (and also tag) : TikzPgf -> Pgfplots.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Since ```\exam``` isn't doesn't play well with ```geometry``` margins, should I use the standard ```\documentclass{article}``` for my math worksheets & test -- most of which are in a 2 column format to save paper.

Comment: Since you aren't using any of exam's features (like \question), absolutely.  I used article for my own worksheets (back when I did worksheets).

Comment: @JohnKormylo In 2 column environment I'm using, ```\task*``` negates 2 columns and forces everything into the left column. That's why I use ```\task```. Please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: @JohnKormylo  please see this link for pic of 1 column result https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUYWp.png

Comment: I stanf corrected.  You use exam class headers and footers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Your images are to wide that can be placed in one line.

**Edit:**
I guess that you like to preserve image width and move them to the left border of columns in `task`.

- To the almost preserve their widths, you need to exploit column width, i.e. image should start at left column borders in `task`.
- This can be done by use of `changepage` package and `\@parboxrestore` command.
- Beside aforementioned you still need to reduce `column-sep` to 0.75\em:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=0.5in,include head]{geometry}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{systeme}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}       % <---
\pgfplotsset{GRID/.style = {    % define common style for images
    width=100mm,
    axis lines=middle,
    axis line style={-stealth,shorten >=-3mm},
    xlabel=$x$, xlabel style={anchor=south west},
    ylabel=$y$, ylabel style={anchor=south east},
    grid=both,
    grid style={draw=gray!25},
    ticklabel style={font=\scriptsize, text=black!50, inner sep=1pt},
    xmin=-10,   xmax=10,
    ymin=-10,   ymax=10,
    xtick distance=2,
    ytick distance=2,
    minor tick num=1,
    tick align=outside,
            }}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

%---------------------------------------------------------- added
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}     
\makeatletter
\newsavebox\restorebox              
\newenvironment{restoretext}%
    {\@parboxrestore%
     \begin{adjustwidth}{-3em}{}%
                \begin{lrbox}{\restorebox}%
                \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}%
    }{\end{minipage}\end{lrbox}
        \usebox\restorebox
        \end{adjustwidth}
     }
\makeatother     
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{enumitem,tasks}
\settasks{
  label-width=2em,
  item-indent=3em,
  label=(\arabic*),
  column-sep=0.75em,    % <---
 }
 \pagestyle{head}
\header{\textbf{Algebra II: Quadratic Systems}}
{}
{ 04/17/23}
\begin{document}

\textbf {SET A: Solve each system by graphing.}

\begin{tasks}(2)   
%Prob #1
\task $\syslineskipcoeff{1}\systeme*{y=2(x+4)^2-5, y=-2x-9}$\\
\medskip
\begin{restoretext}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[GRID]
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{restoretext}

%Prob #2
  \task $\syslineskipcoeff{1}\systeme*{y=2(x+4)^2-3, y=x+7}$\\
\medskip
\begin{restoretext}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[GRID]
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{restoretext}

\bigskip
%Prob #3
\task $\syslineskipcoeff{1}\systeme*
{y=2(x-3)^2+1, 2x+y=11}$\\
\medskip
\begin{restoretext}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[GRID]
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{restoretext}
%Prob #4
\task $\syslineskipcoeff{1}\systeme*
{y=\frac{1}{2}(x-4)^2-3, y=2x-11}$\\
\medskip
\begin{restoretext}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[GRID]
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{restoretext}
\end{tasks}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect solution. Exactly what I was trying to create. One glitch in the rendering...In overleaf, the code produces red-lined boxes. How would I turn those off (i.e. make the boxes non-printing)? https://i.stack.imgur.com/yj3mV.png

Comment: @SiuslawMath, if you woild check code carefully, you would find in third code line `%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!` - So. just follow to this comment and in real document remove this and following four lines ... BTW, if it is perfect solution, than I hope it deserve to be at least up-voted ;-)

Comment: my apologies for the oversight. now upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

This solution uses `\makebox[\columnwidth]{...}` to cram the contents into the task by overlapping both sides.

One can do a better job of evening the margins using `\makebox[\dimexpr \columnwidth-\labelwidth-\labelsep]{...}`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=0.5in,include head,headheight=17pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{systeme}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.18}

\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{enumitem,tasks}
\settasks{
%  after-item-skip=5em,
%  after-skip=2cm,
  label-width=2em,
  item-indent=3em,
  label=(\arabic*),
  column-sep=2em,
 }
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{\textbf{Algebra II: Quadratic Systems}}
\fancyhead[R]{04/17/23}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}

\textbf {SET A: Solve each system by graphing.}

\begin{tasks}(2)
%Prob #1
\task $\syslineskipcoeff{1}\systeme*{y=2(x+4)^2-5, y=-2x-9}$\\
\bigskip
\makebox[\columnwidth]{\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            axis lines=middle,
            axis line style={-stealth,shorten >=-3mm},
            xlabel=$x$, xlabel style={anchor=south west},
            ylabel=$y$, ylabel style={anchor=south east},
            grid=both,
            grid style={draw=gray!25},
            ticklabel style={font=\scriptsize, text=black!50, inner sep=1pt},
            xmin=-10,   xmax=10,          
            ymin=-10,   ymax=10,
            xtick distance=2,
            ytick distance=2,
            minor tick num=1,
            tick align=outside,
        ]
        \end{axis}
        \draw[red] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
    \end{tikzpicture}}
%Prob #2
  \task $\syslineskipcoeff{1}\systeme*{y=2(x+4)^2-3, y=x+7}$\\
\bigskip
\makebox[\columnwidth]{\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            axis lines=middle,
            axis line style={-stealth,shorten >=-3mm},
            xlabel=$x$, xlabel style={anchor=south west},
            ylabel=$y$, ylabel style={anchor=south east},
            grid=both,
            grid style={draw=gray!25},
            ticklabel style={font=\scriptsize, text=black!50, inner sep=1pt},
            xmin=-10,   xmax=10,          
            ymin=-10,   ymax=10,
            xtick distance=2,
            ytick distance=2,
            minor tick num=1,
            tick align=outside,
        ]
        \end{axis}
        \draw[red] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
    \end{tikzpicture}}
% show task margins
\task \rule{\columnwidth}{\ht\strutbox}

\task \rule{\columnwidth}{\ht\strutbox}
\end{tasks}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for all the time you spent providing the solution above.